# how to add SQLcipher to android project?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sqlcipher

Im trying to use SQLCipher to encrypt my database for my project.ive added all the assets and libs requires for using sqlCipher but the problem is that i have an entire class dedicated to just database operations so im a bit confused of where im supposed to be adding the required code as mentioned [here](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/). i did try initializing the said libraries in my database `open()` method but that just gave me a no such table exception.

Heres my code before any modifications. Any help is gratefully accepted

```
public class DataBaseHandler {
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_XCOD = "xcod";
public static final String KEY_YCOD = "ycod";
public static final String KEY_IMG = "img";
public static final String KEY_PATTERN = "pattern";
public static final String KEY_PACKAGENAME = "packagename";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "P3UserDb";
private static final String DATABASE_USERTABLE = "LoginDetailsTable";
private static final String DATABASE_PATTERNTABLE = "PatternDetailsTable";
private static final String DATABASE_LOCKEDAPPSTABLE = "LockedAppsTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

public static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_USERTABLE + " (" + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_XCOD
                + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + KEY_YCOD + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_IMG + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_PATTERNTABLE + " ("
                + KEY_PATTERN + " STRING NOT NULL);");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_LOCKEDAPPSTABLE + " ("
                + KEY_PACKAGENAME + " STRING);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_USERTABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_PATTERNTABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_LOCKEDAPPSTABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public DataBaseHandler(Context c) {
    ourContext = c;
}

public DataBaseHandler open() throws SQLException {
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    ourHelper.close();
}
.
.
.
Other Database operations
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Check this https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/tree/master/dist/SQLCipherForAndroid-SDK

Comment: Why don't you follow a tutorial on SQLCypher.  Posting your "before" code seems pretty lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Before you initialize your `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass, you need to call `SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(…);` passing it a context.  That will properly allow the native libraries to load.